# Javascript not loading properly using rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using rails 3.1.0, coffee-rails 3.1.0, and therubyracer 'v8'.   I see the following error when I try to inspect the compiled javascript using firebug...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/application.js">
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js
</script>
```

Inside app/assets/javascripts/post.js.coffee I have the following code:

```
$(window).resize ->
  if $(window).width() <= 800
    $(".container").css('margin-left', '100px')
    $(".left-slider").html("margin-left 100px")
  else
    $(".container").css('margin-left', '')
    $(".left-slider").html("margin-left 0px")
```

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I'm using this line...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Also, I don't know if this is relevant or not but before the error above popped up I was seeing stale javascript code in firebug.

Comment: While trying to debug this issue the problem mysteriously went away and I am so far unable to reproduce it.  Here are roughly the modifications I made... (1) restarted the browser, (2) up reved config.assets.version, (3) set config.assets.debug to true, restarted rails server a few times.  Any ideas why the issues happened in the first place?

Comment: do u hav any compiled files in your public folder?

Comment: if yes, remove everything or run rake assets:precompile , it may help you.

Comment: shreedhar I appreciate your comments. That may very well have been my issue at the time.  At this point I don't have any compiled files in public and I haven't seen the issue since I reported it.